# Increase height of laser cut design file for enclosure

Tags: inkscape, laser-cutting, laser

I want to create an enclosure case for a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with a GrovePi Hat on top and an LCD display attached.

I found design files for a laser cut case for a Raspberry Pi 3B+ [[1]](https://github.com/diy-electronics/raspberrypi-b-plus-case), as well as the details of the GrovePi [[2]](https://grabcad.com/library/grovepi-1) and the LCD screen [[3]](https://grabcad.com/library/grove-lcd-rgb-backlight-1). Since I'm new to laser cutting, I would like to start from the design files for the Raspberry Pi 3B+, and extend the height of this box a bit.

What would be the best way to approach this (e.g., in InkScape)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would do it in Inkscape

1. Resize the page to give yourself a bit more room.
2. Unsing the Select by Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd> select, then convert the little rectanglular holes to paths using *Path > Stroke to Path*
3. Ungroup the pieces, regroup the top two pieces together
4. Rotate the top group so the pieces are the same way up as the bottom two pieces
5. Using the Select by Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd>, select all the paths you want to move. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking will allow you to make multiple selections
6. While still holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, select the nodes you want to move by clicking and dragging rectangles to encompass those nodes.  The selected nodes will turn blue.
7. Nudge up using the arrow keys

Here I show steps 4 to 7

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The case cutline file you link to is `.svg`, and will work in *any* **competent** vector art or CADD program, from [**InkScape**](https://inkscape.org/) to [**Affinity Designer**](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/) to [**Adobe Illustrator**](https://www.adobe.com/it/products/illustrator.html) to [**Draftsight**](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/download-draftsight/) (was free CADD, now $99 license and darn good too - I use it in architecture to replace AutoCAD and it does everything I need) or even [**AutoCAD**](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwiLutLEpZHiAhVjGH0KHbQfD98YABAAGgJwdg&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASEuRohCMGtCpsLEVOdOBxLnnuPw&sig=AOD64_1nHxNFZzVV3mkcHm0HiqfbnqJTQA&q=&ved=2ahUKEwiEvMzEpZHiAhWlCTQIHRd6AUMQ0Qx6BAgSEAE&adurl=).

However, the two other design files you linked to were SolidWorks files, so for free 3D engineering CADD apps I'd look first at [**Onshape**](https://www.onshape.com/) - it should read these and has a really good robust system, supports assemblies and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: free Draftsight is no more available and already installed free versions stop working in the end of year 2019.

Comment: @user287001 - thanks - I've updated the answer to include this; disappointing, if unsurprising - but for those of us using Draftsight Beta on Mac, I think it remains free for now. I used it for a long time on all three platforms - Mac, Winduhs and Linux - apparently that will become more challenging.